# How to have the value of a key value pair in a dictionary used as a binding value to another view like a Stepper

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would think this should be pretty simple but I am getting an error saying that `Int` is not `Hashable`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var testNumbers : [String : Int] = ["foo" : 1]
    var body: some View {
        Stepper("test", value: $testNumbers["foo", default: 1])
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Subscript index of type '() -> Int' in a key path must be Hashable

Answer (score 1):

`Binding` doesn't have any `Dictionary`-like subscripts built-in, so you'll need to make your own.

```swift
public extension Binding {
  subscript<Key, Value_Value>(
    key: Key,
    default default: Value_Value
  ) -> Binding<Value_Value>
  where Value == [Key: Value_Value] {
    .init(
      get: { wrappedValue[key, default: `default`] },
      set: { wrappedValue[key] = $0 }
    )
  }
}
```

I use the stupid-looking-but-decent-compromise name `Value_Value` because `Self.Value` [can't be used yet](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13995).

Comment: Looks good, I just think `subscript<K, V>` instead of `Value_Value` would be better.

Comment: That's a standard in other language, but not Swift. (Notice no K's or V's here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift) There's no precent for what I'm doing here either, with the underscore, but I'll change it as soon as the compiler bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `Binding` to create a variable of type `Binding <Int>` which is needed in the `Stepper`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var testNumbers: [String: Int] = ["foo": 1]

    var binding: Binding<Int> {
        .init(get: {
            testNumbers["foo", default: 1]
        }, set: {
            testNumbers["foo"] = $0
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        Stepper("test", value: binding)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is alright, but not reusable. I think my answer should be built into SwiftUI instead.